# remaining work by activity as a column or calculated field

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to be able to easily see the sum of remaining work (on a Feature) for each activity.

In this example-picture I have a Feature "Keys 0.1" that I would like to add to my sprint. Say I have 60hrs free in the sprint.

At first glance it looks like I can comfortably add the entire feature without any problems. BUT!

Lets say the sprint has room for 20h frontend work and 40h backend work. If that's the case then I cant really add this Feature since it's too much frontend and not enough backend. Our current sollution is to pretty much add stuff, checking if we're fine and removing if we're not.

Is it possible to somehow get "Sum of remaining work Frontend" and "Sum of remaining work Backend" as columns?

[image]

One thing I tried was to add 2 new custom fields: "Remaining work Frontend" and "Remaining work Backend". This works fine for the backlog, but when I added tasks to my sprint it didn't use those fields to calculate capacity/remaining time. Does anyone have any ideas of how to get a better overview of how much time something will take grouped by activity?

Answer (score 1):

Get "Sum of remaining work Frontend" and "Sum of remaining work Backend" as columns

Steps:

1. Open process->select work item type->add new field Create a field Remaining work Frontend and Remaining work Backend(Type: Decimal).
2. Open Backlog page->Column Options->Add a rollup column->Configure custom rollup->select Roll up as Total and configure the sum column.

In addition, we cannot use these fields to calculate capacity/remaining time.

I hope it can help you.[image]

**Update1**

We found a similar [suggestion ticket.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/763723/enhancements-to-calculated-fields-and-roll-ups.html) You can add comments in the ticket to describe the feature. To receive the notification about it in time, you can vote and follow this suggestion ticket.
I hope this can help you.

Comment: That's just it :P I want to be able to use these fields to calculate capacity/remaining time. It sucks if I have to manually fill out both the custom fields AND the default "remaining time" just to get the sprint-calculation to work

Comment: Please check the Update.